# How to print file/directory details using ls and AWK?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to print the output as below using the command:

```
ls -l| awk '/777/{print $0}'
```

or

```
ls -l| awk '/0777/{print $0}'
```

But it does not print anything.
O/P should be like,

```
drwxrwxrwx  2 sbcoper sbcprd   4096 Apr 20  2015 work
```

(I am using `0777` or `777` because of `find . -type f -perm 0777`)

Comment: [Please don't parse `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you've got the right idea, but 777 is the octal representation of permissions, and with this you're looking at the output of ls, which lists permissions as a string, like "drwxrwxrwx", so a simple modification of your command would work nicely,
`ls -l | awk '/rwxrwxrwx/{print $0}'`